# How do I make use of a nosql db to get the results without writing a lot of javascript?

Tags: sql, node.js, nosql

Say I have following data in CSV

```
Author
authId, firstName, lastName, address, country.

Book
bookId, authId, pubId

Publisher
pubId, pubName

Author_Pub (author's preferred publishers)
authId, pubId
```

I am doing all of this nodeJS. I have converted the data into jsonArrays using an npm package. I am new to NoSQL so trying to get my head around it.

How can I query this data such a way that I get the following results, when the query is country='USA' or 'Russia" and publisher='A' or "B'

```
authId, firstName, lastName, booksPublished
1       joe        shmoe     10
1       john       don       20
```

Now I know I can use joined arrays and use filter etc to get some results. But what I want to do is use a NoSQL DB to reduce some code. Map/Reduce approach may be?

Should I populate this data in CouchDB and use its join capabilities? Ideas welcome.

Comment: You forgot to add your code.

Comment: There is no code, it is more or an approach/architecture question

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. Every NoSQL database is different.

Comment: Right, and I am ready to pick up anyone of them. Question is which one provides, the simplest way of doing it?